# VisualStudio 2017 x64/x86 platform not available

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am using VisualStudio 2017 on Windows 7 with latest updates, and from the configuration manager when I try to set the target platform I am only presented with ARM/ARM64 options, x64/x86 are not even listed. How do I fix this? Should I install some missing plugin etc?

Here is a screenshot [image]

Comment: What processor is your system running on?

Comment: @phuzi Intel i5-4590 64 bit

Comment: It thinks you already have an x86 and x64 platform for the project so doesn't offer them again when you add a new platform.  That's quite normal, they are the default platforms you get from a project template.  If you want to generate x86 code then simply change the active solution platform with the combobox in the toolbar at the top of the main window, the one next to "Debug" and now set to x64.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to start Visual Studio Installer, click *modify* and under Individual Components look for **VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 latest tools** in the *Compilers, build tools, and runtimes* section. AFAIK this is installed by default, but it might be worth checking out to be sure.

**EDIT:**

Never mind, the platforms are already added (by default), notice the "Platform" dropdown. It already says x64, if you change "Active solution platform" to x86 you can also choose Win32 (x86) under the project platform. (Like [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55281146/visualstudio-2017-x64-x86-platform-not-available/55281381#comment97296275_55281146) mentioned)

Comment: It shows the following package already installed - 
VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 latest v141 tools